# Search form with two fields not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making an RoR app that allows users to CRUD guidelines. I also am adding various search functions, including the option to search by two attributes "investor" and "program", which are two text fields in my search form. It's not working. My logic works when searching by one attribute, but not two. This is almost certainly due to me not understanding how to send two text fields as params to a search function, and I can't seem to find enough documentation to find the answer myself.

my model file:

```
def self.invprogsearch(params[:investor], params[:program])
    where(['investor LIKE? && program LIKE?', "%#{investor}%", "%#{program}%"])
  end
```

my index controller

```
def index
   if params[:invprogsearch]
      @guidelines = Guideline.invprogsearch(params[:invprogsearch])
    else
      @guidelines = Guideline.all
    end
  end
```

and my search form

```
<p>Search by Investor and Program</p>
<%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field(:guideline, :program_code, placeholder: "Enter investor") %>
  <%= text_field(:guideline, :investor, placeholder: "Enter program") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I appreciate the help here, I'm anxious to become more proficient in Ruby/Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rework your code like that :

View :

```
<p>Search by Investor and Program</p>
<%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :program_code, nil, placeholder: "Enter investor" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :investor, nil, placeholder: "Enter program" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
def self.invprogsearch(params)
    where('investor LIKE ? AND program LIKE ?', "%#{params[:investor]}%", "%#{params[:program_code]}%")
  end
```

Controller :

```
def index
   if params[:program_code].present? && params[:investor].present?
      @guidelines = Guideline.invprogsearch(params)
    else
      @guidelines = Guideline.all
    end
  end
end
```

Also, here is a cool screencast about implementing a search feature :
https://www.codeschool.com/screencasts/basecamp-search

Comment: I'm getting a "undefined local variable or method `investor' for #<Class:0x007fabef1c3098>" on the definition of the invprogsearch in my model

Comment: Works! thank you very much. I have a better understanding of hashes now.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should read

```
def self.invprogsearch(investor, program)
  where(['investor LIKE ? && program LIKE ?', "%#{investor}%", "%#{program}%"])
end
```

`params` is not set at the time your model definition is being read.

And the controller should say

```
def index
  if params[:invprogsearch]
    @guidelines = Guideline.invprogsearch(params[:investor], params[:program_code])
                                          #     ^-----   Change here
  else
    @guidelines = Guideline.all
  end
end
```

The basic problem is that the names of the fields in your form need to match up with the named of the fields in `params` that you pass into your model.

Comment: there is nothing named invprogsearch in his form

Comment: Also, the value of investor will be at params[:guideline][:investor], not params[:investor]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

Is a good idea to handle scopes for reusage

```
class Guideline < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :by_program_code, -> (program_code) {
        if program_code.present?
            where(arel_table[:program_code].match("%#{program_code}%"))
        else
            current_scope
        end
    }

     scope :by_investor, -> (investor) {
        if investor.present?
            where(arel_table[:investor].match("%#{investor}%"))
        else
            current_scope
        end
    }


    scope :by_program_code_and_investor -> (program_code, investor) {
        by_program_code(program_code).by_investor(investor)
    }
end
```

And in controller

```
class GuidelinesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :guidelines, only: [:index]

    def index; end

    protected 

    def guidelines
        if params[:program_code] && params[:investor] 
            @guidelines ||= Guideline.by_program_code_and_investor(params[:program_code], params[:investor]) 
        end

         @guidelines ||= Guideline.all
    end

end
```

If you want a more flexible search

```
def guidelines
    @guidelines = Guideline
    @guidelines = @guidelines.by_program_code(params[:program_code]) if params[:program_code]
    @guidelines = @guidelines.by_investor(params[:investor]) if params[:investor]
    @guidelines = @guidelines.all 
end
```